# Development Outfit for work on Pi

Tags: software-development, apache-httpd, perl

We have been carrying out an internal project on Pi that has proved very useful. We now want to take it to the next level and 'professionalise' it by hiring a developer(s) to standardise the installation, create an image of our build with the tools installed and to create an attractive HTML5 front-end. (Modules to be used are Apache2, PERL, FastCGI etc.)

This may not be the right place to ask so apologies if that is so but can anyone point me in the right direction for people to work with on this?

Many thanks, Will

Comment: http://www.freelancer.com/ -- http://www.getacoder.com/ -- https://www.elance.com/ ...there are others.

Comment: You can also try the [wanted](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewforum.php?f=61) section of the raspberry forum.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in hiring people from the Stack Exhange community, the best place to do that is [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com).  Stack Exchange sites are not the right place to look for employmees.  Please refer to the [help section](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) of the site for what is an appropriate use of the site.